# NetworkStream.DataAvailable vs. TcpClient.Available

Tags: c#, tcpclient, networkstream

In the following scenario;

```
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient TC = SomeHowObtained;
System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream NS = TC.GetStream();
```

Is there any difference between using `NS.DataAvailable` and checking `TC.Available > 0`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case no, there is no difference. Internally `NS.DataAvailable` returns true when `Socket.Available != 0`. Since `TC.Available` just return `Socket.Available` and you are checking if that is greater than 0 you are basically doing the same thing.

Comment: Indeed [TCPClient.cs source code in C# .NET](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient@cs/1305376/TCPClient@cs) reads `public int Available {get {return m_ClientSocket.Available;}}` and [NetworkStream.cs source code in C# .NET](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Net/System/Net/Sockets/NetworkStream@cs/1305376/NetworkStream@cs) reads `return chkStreamSocket.Available != 0;` .

Answer (score 3):

From the MSDN:

[NetworkStream.DataAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable.aspx)

> Gets a value that indicates whether **data is available on the
>   NetworkStream** to be read.

[TcpClient.Available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.available.aspx)

> Gets the amount of data **that has been received from the network** and is
>   available to be read.

`NetworkStream.DataAvailable` returns `boolean` (true if data is available on the stream to be read), `TcpClient.Available` returns `Int32`(The number of bytes of data received from the network and available to be read)